# Keep IK Controller Leveled

Tags: animation, armature

I am working with a robotic arm animation which uses an armature with an IK Solver. I need the tip of the robot (at the moment it is a polishing wheel) to always remain leveled. The default behavior when posing the controller bone is that the tip of the bone always follows the axis of movement, causing the polishing head to twist and turn. Is there any way to keep that polishing head always leveled?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate question, but it’s a duplicate of something I asked. Yes, thankfully you can easily limit how bones behave with IK. Go to the bone properties tab, and look for “IK settings.”

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yeah, I already have that setup (albeit probably not correctly). The whole mesh is moving around as desired, except that I need the last bone/tip to remain level (in my case to the Y-axis). I just have no idea how to do that!

Comment: Oh, yes. I see. Well, have you tried enabling the rotation tracking thing in the IK constraint, or using a pole target?

Comment: I did the rotation thing within the IK solver, yeah. But the pole target situation is what is confusing me deeply! :P Perhaps that would be a solution! I have posted this same question on Reddit, with a little video: https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/lt4eud/keep_ik_controller_leveled/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand from the video what you're looking for, it seems that the last L shaped block is rigid, having only the wheel rotating, so it should work if you set the IK chain from its start, not from his tip: you can create a "master" bone for this whole object, lock its Z loc and X,Y Rot and use it as target of the IK chain, so that animating the master will always stay correctly on the floor, and the rest of the arm follows as IK.

[image]

Comment: That is an awesome answer! Thank you so much! It might just solve my problem :) Just a question though: Should i erase the whole IK setup I have now? And how exactly do I assigned this "Master" bone at the tip? Thank you again!

Comment: I think you can use yuor actual file until the equivalent of my IK Chain 1 bone, and set an IK constraint on it. In my example the rotor (wheel) bone is simply a child of the master bone.

Comment: Yeah, i have been tryin that and also creating one from scratch. I think it is working in principle but the problem is that my rig (robot) joints can only rotate on one axis (Y). In that way, my Rotor part keeps rotating like crazy because the IK chain cannot resolve the issue. Do you offer some freelance tutoring/coaching perhaps? i thought we could do a 1 or 2 hour tandem on this problem so i can finally solve it with some help :) Let me know if that would be a thing for you! Cheers!

Comment: Send me the .blend file to joshsanfelici@gmail.com. I think it will be a free 5 minutes problem solving. If you need some more infos we will have an agreement.